# CSS animation event not firing in Firefox or Chrome (works in Safari)

Tags: css, animation

I am creating a progress bar component that has a default state and an animated state.  Currently, the animation is only firing in Safari.  For IE 10/11 I came across a known issue in which animation events will not fire for pseudo elements so that one is explained but I believe this should be working for FF and Chrome.  I have done a fair amount of googling and seen similar issues but those solutions usually involved using browser specific pseudo classes to which I have tried but not been successful in getting them to work.  Any thoughts on what could be the cause is greatly appreciated.

```
progress.pe-progress-bar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 4px;
}

progress.pe-progress-bar::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #c7c7c7;
}

progress.pe-progress-bar::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: $pe-color-digital-marine-turquoise;
  height: 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}

progress.pe-progress-bar::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #19a5a3;
  height: 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

progress.pe-progress-bar::-ms-fill {
  background-color: #19a5a3;
  position: relative;
}

progress.pb-animated::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(
            -45deg,
            transparent,
            transparent 8px,
            #daf0ed 8px,
            #daf0ed 12px,
            transparent 12px), #19a5a3;
  background-size: 50px 100%;
  -webkit-animation: animateStripes_w 6s linear infinite;
}

progress.pb-animated::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(
            -45deg,
            transparent,
            transparent 8px,
            #daf0ed 8px,
            #daf0ed 12px,
            transparent 12px), #19a5a3;
  background-size: 50px 100%;
  -moz-animation: animateStripes_m 6s linear infinite;
}

progress.pb-animated::-ms-fill {
  background: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(
            -45deg,
            transparent,
            transparent 8px,
            #daf0ed 8px,
            #daf0ed 12px,
            transparent 12px), #19a5a3;
  background-size: 50px 100%;
  animation: animateStripes 6s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateStripes_w {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
  100% {background-position: -100px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
}

@-moz-keyframes animateStripes_m {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
  100% {background-position: -100px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
}

@keyframes animateStripes {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
  100% {background-position: -100px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
}
```

JSX

```
<div className={`progress-bar-text-${alignLabel}`}>
      <p className="pe-label">
        <span ref={span => this.span = span}>
          {value}</span>{labelText}
      </p>
      <progress
        className={type === 'animated' ? 'pe-progress-bar pb-animated' : 'pe-progress-bar'}
        role="progressbar"
        aria-valuemax={max}
        aria-valuenow={value}
        aria-valuetext={`${value}%`}
        max={max}
        value={value}
        ref={progress => this.progress = progress}
      />
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/. I think you need to style using `progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value`, so if you don't have a value set on your progress bar the styling won't work

Comment: Yeah, I had come across that article too and tried it.  Doesn't work unfortunately.  Everything but the animation gets put on the value.  For instance the background which are teal stripes are present just not moving.

Comment: Can you post you html as well?

Comment: Done.  It's part of a React component so the pertinent JSX is what I included.

Comment: While I don't know why, the pseudo elements are the reason for the animations being blocked.  I stopped using the progress element and went with a div and span for the rail and meter. The animations now work in all of the browsers.